# Loading FaceGen(.fg) file on Android OpenGL workspace

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, mesh

I have to model a 3D face mesh in my openGL workspace.  I have modelled a face using FaceGen software.  It produced .fg file as my 3D face mesh.  Now i want to load or use this 3D information in my Android OpenGL workspace. How can i read its vertices or texture cordinates from that .fg file?

Or suggests any other means for loading some 3D mesh specifically face mesh in OpenGL enviorment.

[UPDATE]: As per preious suggestions I tried writing parser for my 3D object(.obj). I had tried various approaches for 3D objects loading like [Min3D](https://code.google.com/p/min3d/), LIBGDX, Android - GL but I want to parse [FaceGen(.fg)](http://www.facegen.com/modeller.htm) output models. Still I am not able to parse (.fg) format to my Android OpenGL Workspace.

Comment: We're not here to write your code, nor give you links to off-site resources, please take that in mind before posting future question! *Though, to be kind because you're new [try reading this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file)!*

Comment: @Vallentin Thnaks for your quick reply and the wiki link u provided. I read such articles and got idea about wavefront obj files and various other 3D mesh extensions. I am not getting how to read this in android OGL workspace. If you had tried this please give me quick idea to do such thing. Never asked you to write my code.

Comment: Well, read the Wiki page (or any other page), about how the various model files are layed out. When you know that then just create your own parse, which reads the model file line by line, and process the data according to how that format "work".

Comment: Yeah i get your point, thank you very much. I had started reading more about it. Started coding for reading and manuplating this .obj files. I'll get back to you if i face any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

FaceGen's FG format contains a face coordinate in a proprietary face space.

In order to get a 3D mesh and texture image you must load the FG file using FaceGen software (eg. Artist, 3D Print or Modeller) and export.

Comment: This is what i want to confirm. Thank you. If you can provide some saple code for loading .obj on android openGL es would be helpful for me.